# What's the Russian for "Industry professional"?

Tags: перевод

Это человек, который работает в этой области или это человек, который обладает высоким уровнем квалификации в данной области?

Контекст.
Вопрос в анкете:
"Which of the following descriptions best characterizes you?"

Возможные ответы:
"Student/Industry professional/Academic/Professor/Teacher/Hobbyist/Other"

Comment: "специалист в этой области"
or
"специалист в области ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в данном контексте имеется в виду *"человек, работающий в этой области"*.  Для описания *"человека, обладающего высоким уровнем квалификации в этой области"* часто используется фраза *"Industry expert"*.

Comment: Часто профессионал может пониматься двояко, но здесь Вы правы. Cкорее всего имеется в виду "человек, работающий в этой области".